# JS: Posting form directly

Tags: javascript, jquery

If on document.ready, I want my form to auto post itself, is this possible?

So when the document has loaded, then it posts itself and takes to the action="" (in this case is ?upload=true).

I heard about $.post() jquery, but this is just for posting in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `$.post()` in jQuery is for POST requests with AJAX.

If you want a form to submit on the document ready event, just invoke the submit itself!

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
  $('form').submit()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

$.post() is an AJAX call and will not force the entire page to postback.

you may want to try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var form = $("#yourformid");
     form.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#myformid').submit();
});
```

See the [documentation for jQuery's `submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

And see this working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8hg8s/